# Mysql - Take data from row and copy it to another row

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two rows like:

```
Row1        Row2
=======     =======
7,3         text 1
1,3         text 2
1,2,3       blabla
```

What i need to do is add/copy all the text from Row1, at the beginning of row2, plus adding some custom text (CRLF). Something like:

```
Row1        Row2
=======     =======
7,3         7,3<br />text 1
1,3         1,3<br />text 2
1,2,3       1,2,3<br />blabla
```

So, is there a way to do that using MySQL commands?

Thanks
Lucas

Comment: . . Do you have two rows or two columns?  The term "cognitive dissonance" arises when someone puts data into two columns, but calls them rows.  In other words, I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

If Row1 and Row2 are two separate columns then you can do it like this:

```
update mytable set Row2=concat(Row1,' some text ',Row2);
```

Comment: If my answer was working then please also mark my answer as the correct one so the question can be closed.